# Task serialization error with the third-party library

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I try to solve Spark 2.2 serialization problem. The error is well-known and I was normally solving it using `forEachPartition` or `mapPartitions`.
However, now this approach does not work. I have the object `modCol` that is of the third-party library.

```
val modCol = // Non-serializable object

val rdd = myRDD.mapPartitions{ iter =>
  val c = modCol
  iter.map(
    x => {
    (x.getId, x.getAttribute(c))
  })
}

val df = rdd.toDF()
```

However, I get Task serialization error for `c`:

`Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.gephi.graph.impl.ColumnImpl`

My final goal is to create a DataFrame `df`.

Answer (score 0):

> The error is well-known and I was normally solving it using forEachPartition or mapPartitions.

Indeed, but you don't use it correctly. Don't initialize object in outer scope. Initialize it in the function call:

```
val rdd = myRDD.mapPartitions{ iter =>
  val modCol = ???
  iter.map(
    x => {
      (x.getId, x.getAttribute(modCol))
  })
}
```